# iterate over column in df without making the column its own df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, mongodb, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe with the following columns:

```
Index(['_id', 'author', 'title', 'description', 'url', 'urlToImage',
       'publishedAt', 'content', 'summarization', 'source_id'],
      dtype='object')
```

I wanted to remove html tags, some regex, and strings from text within the column, so i made the column its own df (`content = articles['content']`) and wrote the script below:

```
import re

def remove_tags(text):
    return re.sub(r'<[^>]+>', '', text)
def remove_tags2(text):
    return re.sub(r'\r\n', ' ', text)
def remove_share(text):
    return re.sub(r'Share to facebook|Share to twitter|Share to linkedin|Share on Facebook|Share on Twitter|Share on Messenger|Share on Whatsapp', '', text)
content = [remove_tags(text) for text in content]
content = pd.Series(content, name='content')
content = [remove_tags2(text) for text in content]
content = pd.Series(content, name='content')
content = [remove_share(text) for text in content]
content = pd.Series(content, name='content')
content
```

This works with the column as a df. However, the problem i have is, i should've never made the column into a df and should have `inplace=True` the entire script; which I have no idea how to do.

What do i need to change in the script so that I can still remove what I want without making the column its own df?

**Adding another issues to the same question.**

The following code was also created when the column was its own df. What do i need to change to address the original dataframe?

```
relevant_words = ['Marijuana', 'marijuana', 'Cannabis', 'cannabis', 'THC', 'thc', 'CBD', 'cbd', 'Hemp', 'hemp']
content = content[content.str.contains('|'.join(relevant_words))].str.lower()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain them with `apply`:

```
df['content'] = (df['content']
   .apply(remove_tags)
   .apply(remove_tags2)
   .apply(remove_share)
)
```

You can also create a dictionary and use `.replace`:

```
repl = {r'<[^>]+>': '', 
        r'\r\n': ' ',
        r'Share to facebook|Share to twitter|Share to linkedin|Share on Facebook|Share on Twitter|Share on Messenger|Share on Whatsapp': ''}

df['content'] = df['content'].replace(repl, regex=True)
```

Comment: Thank you I used  the .replace. I added another issue, can you assist with that one, or would it be better if i create a new question?